# JSON LD MusicGroup Markup

Tags: json

I am in a country blues band called the Fly By Night Rounders.   I am attempting to mark up our band, and am a bit confused on how to write in the members for within the band itself (there are 3 of us), and am wondering is it at all possible to mark up *more than one music group within a website...* our band members all have solo careers too.  Will doing all this confuse google?  Please have patience with me... I'm just a DIY music maker.

1. What exactly is the correct way to write JSON-LD for a band, and showcase its members too?
2. Can I also mark up each of the band members separately on the same website to highlight their solo stuff too- or would that be too much markup for google on one site?

http://fbnrblues.com/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: - What exactly is the correct way to write JSON-LD for a band, and showcase its members too?
Can I also mark up each of the band members separately on the same website to highlight their solo stuff too- or would that be too much markup for google on one site?   I'm fairly new to JSON LD